# Cordova + ionic window.open no way to get back

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Im currently using the below code to bring up a website in my angular/ionic/cordova application :

```
var url = 'https://portal.sagepay.com/mysagepay/login.msp';
   var mywindow = window.open(url, '_blank', "EnableViewPortScale=yes" );
```

In phone gap, there is a back button but once published via Xcode and you hit this code, the browser opens and you are then stuck and have to close the app. Ive tried _self and the native one but neither offer the option to go back. Ive even tried to set the height so i could add a back button at the top.